# I can't start mysql server after modifying data folder - Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I used the following command on terminal (Mac 10.11.6) to copy database (map) from backup disk (Time Machine) from old `mysql` folder I had.

```
sudo cp -R  '/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/MacBook Pro/2016-09-26-212804/Macintosh HD/usr/local/mysql/data/map' /usr/local/mysql/data/map
```

It did copy the database but I couldn't start mysql server again .

I used this command :

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

I get this error :

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/computerName-MBP.pid).

Comment: "Remove" (=move it somewhere else in case you need it back) the pid file (it's a way to have process locks)

Comment: @Xenos I tried this `sudo mv /usr/local/mysql/data/computerName-MBP.pid /usr/local/` I want to move it to local but I get `No such file or directory`

Comment: So that pid file does not exist? Or is the `usr/local/` not found?! This file should contain the PID (process ID) of the server. So either it already exist  or server cannot create it when started (check permissions).

Comment: @Xenos  I get this exactly : `mv: rename /usr/local/mysql/data/computerName-MBP.pid to /usr/local/computerName-MBP.pid: No such file or directory
` why it tells me to rename it !!

Comment: If you `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/computerName-MBP.pid`, then do you have a result? If yes, it means the file exist, and you're trying to move it to `usr/local` which does not exist/is not reachable. If no, it means the file does not exist, and MySQL is probably missing the rights to write files in your `/usr/local/mysql/data/` folder.

Comment: @Xenos actually .pid file doesn't exist ! , mysql was working good before coping another database to data folder , where did .pid file go? what should I do now ?

Comment: "MySQL is probably missing the rights to write files in your /usr/local/mysql/data/ folder." so check the folder's permissions (user/group, or `chmod 777` to quickly find out if that's the issue).

Comment: @Xenos mysql and folders has `777 ` permission